# Java bitcoinj: semantics of 'decompress' on encrypted key

Tags: private-key, public-key, bitcoinj, encryption

Calling the `decompress` method on an encrypted `ECKey` object yields an `ECKey` object which has no private key (only public). I personally would have expected to get the same encrypted key in uncompressed format (i.e. nothing changes except the encoding of the public elliptic curve point). Can anyone comment on whether there is a good reason for the API to be the way it is, or whether this is most likely an oversight? I attach a snippet for illustration:

```
import org.bitcoinj.core.ECKey;
import org.bitcoinj.crypto.KeyCrypter;
import org.bitcoinj.crypto.KeyCrypterScrypt;

import org.spongycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    ECKey k1 = new ECKey(); // some random (compressed) key

    // encrypting k1
    KeyCrypter crypter = new KeyCrypterScrypt();
    KeyParameter aesKey = crypter.deriveKey("some arbitrary passphrase");
    ECKey k2 = k1.encrypt(crypter, aesKey);

    // a few checks
    System.out.println(k2.isCompressed()); // true
    System.out.println(k2.isEncrypted());  // true
    System.out.println(k2.isPubKeyOnly()); // true  (private key not available)
    System.out.println(k2.isWatching());   // false (but it has a private key)

    // now decompressing encrypted key
    ECKey k3 = k2.decompress();

    // a few more checks
    System.out.println(k3.isCompressed()); // false
    System.out.println(k3.isEncrypted());  // false (hmmm, really?)
    System.out.println(k3.isPubKeyOnly()); // true  (private key not available)
    System.out.println(k3.isWatching());   // true  (because there is none)

    // Esentially same public key, but third has leading byte 0x04 (uncompressed)
    System.out.println(k1.getPublicKeyAsHex());  // 03585c156c1449155420 ...
    System.out.println(k2.getPublicKeyAsHex());  // 03585c156c1449155420 ...
    System.out.println(k3.getPublicKeyAsHex());  // 04585c156c1449155420 ...
  }
}
```